# PHP дата, как свойство класса

Tags: php, datetime

Пытался получить ответ в google, но, возможно, я не так задавал вопрос и не нашел ответ.

Вопрос: как правильно работать с датами в PHP при объектно-ориентированном подходе.
До сих пор во всех классах свойства, представляющие дату (время) я заполнял timestamp числом. 
"Чувствую", что правильнее использовать стандартный класс DateTime.
Но, с другой стороны объект использует больше памяти, и, соответственно, должен медленней работать, что при большом количестве объектов с большим количеством полей DateTime негативно скажется на производительности (например, страница с сотней записей (= 100 объектов), в каждом из которых около 5-и полей типа DateTime).

Подскажите "правильный" подход, или где про него можно почитать.

Спасибо.

Comment: А вы проверяли насколько медленнее работает с DateTime?

Comment: Хранить можно в timestamp (int), и для работы его использовать в этом виде, а вот для вывода и трансформаций удобнее использовать статические функции DateTime где возможно, без создания объекта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`100 DateTime`? Вы этого даже не почувствуете. Даже `1000` и даже `10000`.

Попытаюсь вам донести **лично мое мнение**, хотя ораторские навыки у меня на 0.

Смотрите, при разработке проекта, у вас есть 2 противоположные стороны: `быстродействие` и `архитектура`. Занимаясь одной частью, вы жертвуете другой (это аксиома).

У каждой части свои плюсы и минусы: например, макся `быстродействие`, логично, что вы жертвуете архитектурой проекта, вы получаете минимальное время генерации страницы, однако в перспективном будущем, у вас возникнут проблемы с расширением проекта. `Архитектура` проекта - это способ стандартизировать и свести к одной мысли логику **всего** приложения. Когда мы говорим о паттернах - мы сводим логику не просто к одной мысли, а к частоиспользуемой. Т.е. новый программист сможет легко ориентироваться в новом, для него, проекте, зная только принципы, на которых он построен. Архитектура проекта не отталкивается от `быстродействия`, у архитектуры другие критерии: гибкость, масштабируемость, показатель оптимизации и т.д.

Ваш вопрос носит архитектурный характер, а именно `гибкость`. Можно сказать что используя `DateTime` вы увеличиваете гибкость, но уменьшаете `быстродействие`. Думаю это логично, теперь вопрос в том: на сколько это обоснованно (это критерий оптимизации). Тут все индивидуально и зависит от проекта и от задач, полной информацией владеете только вы.

**P.S.** Как программист, вы несете ответственность за то, что вы накодили :) Как говорил мне один дядюшка: Чем больше кода - тем больше ответственность. Решение принимаете вы, и спрашивать будут с вас, а не с нас. А чтобы принять решение - надо понимать полную картину. Одно дело когда вы ставите сервер с сайтом на 2ой пентак, другое дело когда у вас кучка ксенонов (где мощности позволяют создать мощную и гибкую структуру). Ваша задача понимать, в какой пропорции должно быть отношение `быстродействие-архитектура`. Если кто-то скажет, юзайте `DateTime` - он будет прав, и если кто-то скажет что не надо, он тоже будет прав, но с другой стороны.

Вы должны понимать какие манипуляции будут с этой датой, на сколько сильно это повлияет, какой профит вам даст использование DateTime для других частей программы. И что будет при расширении приложения и т.д. - Все это критерий для выбора того или иного подхода, любое что вы выберете будет правильным, если сможете это обосновать (а вы должны уметь это делать).

**P.S.2.** Отвечая на конкретный вопрос: При ООП правильно использовать `DateTime()`

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Для себя определился в пользу DateTime.